# Android - How to measure a 'any size' view wrapped in a constraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

ConstraintLayout needs two passes before it measures itself for views that can be any size (views with 0dp for dimension). So i have a view that is ratio based and i want to meausure how big its going to be before the view is seen by the user.  I am doing this is a adapter for a recyclerview if that matters.  what i have tried so far is the following:

```
iv.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
width = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
height = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
```

and here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,3:2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but this always returns me 1 for width and 1 for height.  How can i get the actual measurements ?

the reason i need the view measured is to construct a url. here is an example url i need:

```
mywebsiteAtImgix.com/img/books/20170316171929_6b1c02a5.jpg?auto=compress&dpr=1&fit=clip&ixlib=java-1.1.1&q=75&w=1&h=1
```

**MORE INFO:** 
i am using a company called imgix and they scale all my images for me. tis very fast and they cache etc so its useful for web images.
Anyway, notice that the query params have a width called "w" and height "h".  right now they are coming in as 1 but for non constraintlayout imageviews when i measure it i get the dimensions ok and the image returned from imgix is a good size.  if i use 1 and 1 for dimensions it brings me back the original image which is extemely large (2mb to 5mb +).  i need go get the dimensions from the constraintLayout so i can properly construct the URL. hope this clears things up.

Comment: No. I insert the drawable after i know the width and height dimensions. I am actually doing a web call after i cinstruct the url for the image. But that url needs height and width of image. Its a company called imgix

Comment: I just need a way to measure a constraint layout beforw its seen by user

Comment: thank you for following up. i updated my question so you can see why i need it. basically . i need to build a url with the height and width of the view.  the imgix company will then provide me the image at that exact width and height. android will not scale anything . the images are very crisps and are fast to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html) to get the bounds of your image directly right before the layout is shown to the user.

> **onPreDraw**
>
> boolean onPreDraw ()
>
> Callback method to be invoked when the view tree is about to be drawn. At this point, all views in the tree have been measured and given a frame. Clients can use this to adjust their scroll bounds or even to request a new layout before drawing occurs.

Comment: its working.  i actually was concerned it would not work with constraintLayout any size views. thanks!